# twilio webhook custom paramters

Tags: twilio

Is it possible to define custom data in outbound SMS/IVR call and receive same data back on callbackurl/webhook. I want to receive few custom parameters (apart from what twilio sends) when my webhook is called.

Answer (score 2):

Try appending the custom data as URL query parameters to the URL you give Twilio to fetch the TwiML. SMS is a different animal, since it doesn't request TwiML like voice does.

[How to Share Information Between Your Applications](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/how-share-information-between-your-applications)